# Why my accuracy values don't change on my train model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

When I start to train my model, Loss values decreasing but Accuracy values never change.I don't know why?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



#Libraries
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import autograd, nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torch.utils import data


"""
Olivetti face dataset
"""
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces

# Olivetti dataset download
olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()
train = olivetti.images
label = olivetti.target

X = train
Y = label
print("Format for X:", X.shape)
print("Format for Y: ", Y.shape)

print("\nDownload Ok")


"""
Set for train
"""
train_rate = 0.8

X_train = np.zeros([int(train_rate * X.shape[0]),64,64], dtype=float)
Y_train = np.zeros([int(train_rate * X.shape[0])], dtype=int)

X_val = np.zeros([int((1-train_rate) * X.shape[0]+1),64,64], dtype=float)
Y_val = np.zeros([int((1-train_rate) * X.shape[0]+1)], dtype=int)

#Split data for train and validation
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    ie=0
    iv=0
    if (i%10)/10 >= train_rate:
        X_train[ie] = X[i]
        Y_train[ie] = Y[i]
        ie += 1
    else:
        X_val[iv] = X[i]
        Y_val[iv] = Y[i]
        iv += 1

X_train = X_train.reshape(320,-1,64,64)
X_val = X_val.reshape(80,-1,64,64)

print(Y_train.shape)
X_train = torch.Tensor(X_train)
Y_train = torch.Tensor(Y_train)

X_val = torch.Tensor(X_val)
Y_val = torch.Tensor(Y_val)  

batch_size = 20

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_train, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            )
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_val, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size, 
                                            )

class CNNModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModule, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 13 * 13, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 40)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 13 * 13)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


def make_train(model,dataset,n_iters,gpu):

    # Organize data
    X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val = dataset

    kriter = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

    #Arrays to save loss and accuracy
    tl=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For train loss
    ta=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For train accuracy
    vl=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For validation loss
    va=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For validation accuracy

    # Convert labels to long
    Y_train = Y_train.long()
    Y_val = Y_val.long()

    # GPU control
    if gpu:
        X_train,Y_train = X_train.cuda(),Y_train.cuda()
        X_val,Y_val = X_val.cuda(),Y_val.cuda()
        model = model.cuda() # Parameters to GPU!
        print("Using GPU")
    else:
        print("Using CPU")
        # print(X_train.shape)
        # print(Y_train.shape)

    for i in range(n_iters):  


        # train forward
        train_out = model.forward(X_train)
        train_loss = kriter(train_out,Y_train)

        # Backward and optimization
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()


        # Compute train accuracy
        train_predict = train_out.cpu().detach().argmax(dim=1)
        train_accuracy = (train_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_train.cpu().numpy()).mean() 

        # For validation
        val_out = model.forward(X_val)
        val_loss = kriter(val_out,Y_val)

        # Compute validation accuracy
        val_predict = val_out.cpu().detach().argmax(dim=1)
        val_accuracy = (val_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_val.cpu().numpy()).mean()

        tl[i] = train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        ta[i] = train_accuracy
        vl[i] = val_loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        va[i] = val_accuracy

        # Show result each 5 loop
        if i%5==0:
            print("Loop --> ",i)
            print("Train Loss :",train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy())
            print("Train Accuracy :",train_accuracy)
            print("Validation Loss :",val_loss.cpu().detach().numpy())
            print("Validation Accuracy :",val_accuracy)

    model = model.cpu()

    #Print result
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), tl, 'r-')
    plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), ta, 'b--')

    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), vl, 'r-')
    plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), va, 'b--')    


dataset = X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val

gpu =  True
gpu = gpu and torch.cuda.is_available() 


model = CNNModule()
make_train(model,dataset,100,gpu)
```

OUTPUT:

Using CPU
Loop -->  0
Train Loss : 3.6302185
Train Accuracy : 0.0
Validation Loss : 3.6171098
Validation Accuracy : 0.0
Loop -->  5
Train Loss : 3.557933
Train Accuracy : 0.996875
Validation Loss : 3.545982
Validation Accuracy : 0.9875
.
.
.
Loop -->  95
Train Loss : 0.04211783
Train Accuracy : 0.996875
Validation Loss : 0.13397054
Validation Accuracy : 0.9875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code,

`train_accuracy = (train_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_train.cpu().numpy()).mean()`
you are taking mean of correct values that's why you are getting same answer in every loop.  Instead you should divide the total correct numbers with total number of examples to find the accuracy.

Comment: train_accuracy = (train_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_train.cpu().numpy()).sum()
train_accuracy = train_accuracy/total_examples

Comment: I think your total examples are 320

Comment: When I changed code like you said   train_accuracy = (train_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_train.cpu().numpy()).sum() 
        train_accuracy = train_accuracy/320    Train Accuracy : 0.996875 and never change again

Comment: can you print few values of train_predict and Y_train.

Comment: train predict- -> tensor([19,19,19,19,19,19,19 and next loops  tensor([0,0,0,0,0,0,0      Y_train  -->tensor([39,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  ...

Comment: I apologies in advance, what is the shape of X_train after the following command. X_train = np.zeros([int(train_rate * X.shape[0]),64,64], dtype=float)

Comment: torch.Size([320, 1, 64, 64])

Comment: Sorry for late reply, In your for loop where you spiting your data in training and validation sets, the variables ie, and iv should be initialized out of for loop. Whereas in you code it was initialized within for loop as a result ie and iv values never goes beyond 1. So there is only train data in X_train[0] all others are zeros. I checked it by running your code in my machine.

Comment: And if (i%10)/10 <= train_rate:   this should be if (i%10)/9 <= train_rate: for 320 training examples and 80 validation examples.

Comment: I got to out of loop ie and iv and changed if structure like you said.Now error that I got  X_val[iv] = X[i]

IndexError: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 80

Comment: Use this if (i%10)/9 <= train_rate: as I mentioned above, the index error will be removed

Comment: You are welcomed. Another suggestion is, increase the filter depth in conv1 and conv2 layers. For good training, filter depths in both layers should be more than number of classes in output layer.

Comment: But still my results are unexpected     Loop -->  0
Train Loss : 3.6918998
Train Accuracy : 0.025
Validation Loss : 3.6916022
Validation Accuracy : 0.025..............Loop -->  400
Train Loss : 3.6878505
Train Accuracy : 0.025
Validation Loss : 3.6880734
Validation Accuracy : 0.025

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yesterday I run your code the only change I did was that I used following combinations of neural network, self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 80, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(80, 240, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(240 * 13 * 13, 10140)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10140, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 40),  and no of iterations are 1000. With that I achieved 0.99 Train accuracy and 0.88 valid accuracy.